Why parameters in function value is allowed to discard when implement call signature in typescript
I am learning about call signatures concept in typescript. I saw an odd case by chance that: "function values are assigned to variables whose type is function type defined by using interface can omit some parameters at the end".
the following code is the one i had run:
interface Caculator {
    (num:number,msg:string):number
}

let getDoule : Caculator = function(num:number){    // missing the last param
    return num*2;
}

let getOne:Caculator =()=>{ // missing all params
    return 1
}

typescript compiler did not throw any error when i run the code above. This is the strange thing make me confused.
However, When calling the two functions in the code above, typescript compiler enforce me make calls that have 2 params (num and msg).
getDoule(1,'ahihi');

getOne(1900,'ahihi');

If I intentionally make calls like:
getDoule(1);

getOne();

The compiler immediately throws error.
Can you tell me why typescript accepts implementations of call signatures like the example above

Because JavaScript doesn't care about additional parameters; your code works just fine and both implementations of Calculator can be called with two arguments. See e.g. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#parameter-arity-variance-is-correct
